# Как организовать атомарную запись в файл из нескольких процессов на .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, f#

Есть несколько программ под .NET Framework 4.6.1. Все они дописывают данные в один текстовый файл.

Как правильно организовать атомарную запись в файл из несколько процессов, т.е. что бы одна запись не разбивалась другой, и в то же время ни один процесс не блокировал файл для другого процесса?
И надо сделать это без мьютексов. Записи сами по себе небольшие, укладываются в 4096 байт.

#### UPD

Уточняю, (наверное, это важный момент) нужно дописывать файл данными. Например, как лог файл.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82873/discussion-on-question-by-mals--------).

Comment: Из вашего вопроса: «что бы одна запись не разбивалась другой, и в то же время ни один процесс не блокировал файл для другого процесса?» — требования выглядят противоречащими друг другу.

Comment: @VladD Плохо, что ЮрийСПб убрал комментарии в чат, там есть ссылки. Нет, нету противоречий.

Comment: @MaLS: Возможно, стоит перенести релевантную часть обсуждения из чата в вопрос?

Comment: @VladD Какую? Просто меня интересуют возможные практики. Пока я вычитал две [FILE_APPEND_DATA](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/atomic-shared-log-file-writes/) и [MoveFileEx](https://antonymale.co.uk/windows-atomic-file-writes.html). Потестирую. Потом выложу тут. Думал, народ ещё подкинет. Если можешь что-то добавить в вопрос я не против.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую ответить.
Возьмём за строгое требование что записи не должны смешиваться.
Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Пишем в один файл из всех процессов, каждый процесс блокирует файл перед записью и разблокирует после.
2. Каждый процесс пишет в свой файл.
3. Без `lock`-ов. Каждый процесс пишет в некоторую шину, данные из которой попадают в файл посредством еще одной программы. Тут достаточно абстрактно описал, попробую пояснить разные варианты:

   3.1. Каждый процесс пишет в свой файл. Есть программа, которая только читает все файлы и записывает в общий файл. Если требуется строгий порядок записей - можно придумать механизм, например к сообщению прикреплять timestamp. Такой своеобразный merge-tool можно даже запускать по расписанию, либо оставлять работать на постоянку.

   3.2. Каждый процесс отправляет сообщения в сервис, где они ставятся в общую очередь и по порядку записываются в нужный файл обработчиком очереди.

Общая идея в том, что нам либо нужен `lock`-механизм, либо единая точка записи сообщений в файл. Ну, либо разные файлы.

Comment: Пункт 1. идёт в противоречие с условием _"один процесс не блокировал файл для другого"_.

Comment: И хотелось бы пример.

Comment: Мне тоже сразу пришла мысль о пункте 3: дополнительный сервис.

Comment: Я взял за требование "Записи не смешиваются" и рассмотрел все варианты.
Пример достаточно конкретный. Сокращу написанное выше. В качестве шины можно использовать либо сервис, либо, если не хочется париться, писать в отдельные файлы и написать аггрегатор (merge-tool).